# Difference between int? i = null and int? i = 0x0

Tags: c#, null

I am writing unit tests to test if my methods will work with nulls as various properties and parameters. For one of the tests I want to use the hex value for null `0x0` as `null` to see if the `int` parameter is caught or `null` is caught.

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetFoo_throws_exception_when_foo_has_null_id()
    {
        int? nullFooId = 0x0; // would this be defined as int or null?

        Foo foo = new Foo
        {
            FooId = nullFooId.Value
        };

        Action action = () => _sut.GetFoo(nullFooId.Value);
        action.ShouldThrow<KeyNotFoundException>();
    }
```

I'm wondering if the `nullFooId` will be `null` or an `int` and why. As well, if I explicitly put `_sut.GetFoo(0x0)`, is it up to the compiler whether to look for the `null` or `int` representation? Does it try to find the proper number of bits?

Comment: 0x0 is 0 in hex notation, not null.

Comment: *"For one of the tests I want to use the hex value for null 0x0 as null"*, You can't use 0x0 as `null`, as the above comment says. 0x0 == 0, 0x0 != null.

Answer (score 0):

`nullFooId` will be `0`, not `null`. If you want it to be null, just set it to `null`.

There is nothing about "finding the proper number of bits". If there are *any* bits (i.e. it is a number), your `nullFooId` will be non-null.

Comment: Is there any representation for `null` other than the explicit `null` value?

Comment: @user2958542 Not in a "safe" context.  In the C++ world setting a _pointer_ to 0 was the same as setting it to `null`.  In C# you can only do that in an `unsafe` context (which should not be used unless _absolutely_ necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [C# grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx), `0x0` is an integer literal of type `int`, with a value of decimal 0.

And given that the expression `0x0 == null` evaluates to `false`, what value do you think `int? x = 0x0;` will assign to `x`?

Further, you say

> I'm wondering if the `nullFooId` will be `null` or an `int` and why.

which suggests a fundamental misunderstanding. Your `nullFooId` is of type `Nullable<int>`, a `struct` with two properties that looks [something like] the following. Note that there is compiler magic that happens under the covers, since support for this is baked into the language itself:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
  private bool hasValue ;
  internal T   value ;

  public bool HasValue { get { return this.hasValue ; } }

  public T Value
  {
    get
    {
      if (!this.hasValue) ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_NoValue);
      return this.value;
    }
  }

}
```